# Listener-Parser in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, listener, antlr4

**ANTLR4 rule :**

```
listExpr locals [Object in, Object out]  :   ( expr ',')* expr  ;
```

**Parser :**

```
public static class ListExprContext extends ParserRuleContext {
    public Object in;
    public Object out;
    public List<ExprContext> expr() {
        return getRuleContexts(ExprContext.class);
    }
....
}
```

**Listener :**

```
override def exitListExpr(ctx : BKOOLParser.ListExprContext) : Unit =
{
val listExpr = ctx.expr
val length = listExpr.length
ctx.out = length
}
```

I want to have the numbers of expr I have in ListExpr,but I have the error :

```
the result type of an implicit must be more specific than AnyRef
```

at line :

```
ctx.out = length
```

How to fix it ? Your help will be appreciated .